# PySerial Creating a Newline for Easy Reading

Tags: python, pyserial

So this is my second time posting on SO, and I must say I really appreciate all the help I've received from the first post. This is a wonderful community.

I'm using Python with PySerial to send some data from one device to another. Here's what I got:

```
import serial
s=serial.Serial(2) #defining COM port 3 for device 1
r=serial.Serial(3) #defining COM port 4 for device 2
s.timeout=3
r.timeout=3
s.write('The time is ')
s.write('The day is ')
s.write('The temp is ')
r.readline()
```

and I receive on the output 'The time is The day is The temp is'

How could I get the output to say:

The time is

The day is

The temp is

?

I've tried using \n to each of them, for example, s.write('The time is \n') to create a newline but this causes and eol, which means, in the end if I do a r.readline() I receive 'The time is \n'

Comment: Maybe I need to include some sort of python library. I'm not sure. I'm very novice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are only doing one `readline()`. readline will read until it reaches a `\n` or it times out. Since you are doing three writes you will need three reads to get all the data.

```
import serial
s=serial.Serial(2) #defining COM port 3 for device 1
r=serial.Serial(3) #defining COM port 4 for device 2
s.timeout=3
r.timeout=3
s.write('The time is ')
s.write('The day is ')
s.write('The temp is ')
# need three reads to read all three of the messages you sent
print r.readline()
print r.readline()
print r.readline()
```